# Getting an error related to react-dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs

I just updated my node and npm installations and now getting an error when I run my project. I am using "react": "^0.13.3" and "react-dom": "0.14.0-beta3"

```
   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react-dom requires react@'^0.14.0-beta3' but will load
    npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react,
    npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.13.3

react-dom requires react@'^0.14.0-beta3'

Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactDOMServer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react-dom/server.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Is there anyway to use react-dom with react 0.13.3? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React 13.3 already has the DOM stuff in it.  It's just called `React.DOM`.  In more recent versions, they've moved this out of the core -- in order to lighten it -- into the optional module.